# Sorting Query Results by Title in Vapor-Fluent

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent, server-side-swift

Query in Fluent, I'm attempting to sort the results by title in Danish language. The current code is functional, but it seems that characters like å, æ, and ø are not being sorted correctly. Does anyone have insights on how to address this issue?

```
// Attraction table
final class Attraction: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "attractions"

    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: FieldKeys.title)
    var title: String

    @OptionalField(key: FieldKeys.description)
    var description: String?

    init() { }

    init(id: UUID? = nil,
         title: String,
         description: String? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
    }

}
extension Attraction {
    enum FieldKeys {
        static let title: FieldKey = "title"
        static let description: FieldKey = "description"
    }
}


// create attraction
struct CreateAttraction: AsyncMigration {

    func prepare(on database: Database) async throws {
        try await database.schema(Attraction.schema)
            .id()
            .field(Attraction.FieldKeys.title, .string, .required)
            .field(Attraction.FieldKeys.description, .string, .required)
            .create()
    }

    func revert(on database: Database) async throws {
        try await database.schema(Attraction.schema).delete()
    }
}

// Add migration in configure file.
app.migrations.add(CreateAttraction())


struct AttractionsController : RouteCollection {
    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {

        routes.get("attractions", use: getAttractionsHandler)
    }

    func getAttractionsHandler(_ req: Request) async throws -> [Attraction] {

        let attractions = try await .query(on: req.db)
            .sort(Attraction.FieldKeys.title)// here å, æ, and ø is not sorting proper way.
            .all()

        return attractions

    }

}
```

in this code i want to fix sorting danish special characters like å, æ, and ø.

Comment: Intuitively, it will be the table collation that is at fault. Try creating your table using the normal `vapor Migration` and then using `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY ...` to change the collation of the column.

Comment: I already created Attraction table using Vapor Migration and it working fine. But when I use .sort() query builder the danish special characters is not sorting properly.

Comment: i update my full code  can you check this